# Azure login problems in deployed Streamlit app

Tags: python, azure, deployment, streamlit, two-factor-authentication

I have a streamlit app that runs perfectly locally but is not possible to deploy it. I have this line:

```
cmd = ['az', 'login']
result = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, text=True)
```

that opens a web browser locally but when I deploy it it does not open any browser, and keeps running forever.

The problem is that I want it to log in using that specific command since the Azure account is a 2FA account, and the usual way of putting `az login -u username -p password`, doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

***Streamlit is a stateless application, Thus using `az login` in an interactive way is not possible, You need to integrate Streamlit app with Flask app and add Azure Authentication step to authenticate with. Refer this [**sample**](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-flask-webapp-authentication).*** An alternative is to create an Azure AD application and use it for authentication and login to your stream lit app integrated with Flask.

I tried a simple Streamlit code that runs `az login` command with `--device-code`

[image]

[image]

[image]

**My** **app.py code**:-

```py
import streamlit as st
from azure.cli.core import get_default_cli
import threading

# Function to run 'az login --use-device-code' command in a separate thread
def run_az_login():
    cli = get_default_cli()
    device_code, url = cli.invoke(['login', '--use-device-code'])
    st.session_state.device_code = device_code
    st.session_state.url = url

# Main Streamlit app code
def main():
    st.title("Azure CLI Interactive Sign-In")

    if 'device_code' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.device_code = None
        st.session_state.url = None

    # Check if the user is logged in
    if st.session_state.device_code is None:
        st.write("Not logged in to Azure CLI.")

        # Button to initiate the login process
        if st.button("Log in to Azure CLI"):
            st.write("Running Azure CLI login...")
            login_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_az_login)
            login_thread.start()
    else:
        st.write("You are logged in to Azure CLI.")
        st.write("Device code:", st.session_state.device_code)
        st.write("URL:", st.session_state.url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code won't redirect you to the **https://microsoft.com/devicelogin** but the same url will be visible in your Log stream section, As Log stream shows the Live start up logs of your Web app below:-

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Got this after signing in:
'''
Exception in thread Thread-4 (run_az_login):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/faaronts/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/faaronts/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/faaronts/Documents/GH PR/research/reports/Notebook-viewer/sl_azure.py", line 8, in run_az_login
    device_code, url = cli.invoke(['login', '--use-device-code'])
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
'''